# Save a csv file to a directory using PHP but without a form

Tags: php, csv, save, fwrite

I'm trying to create some code that will allow me to save a csv file, that is created on a php page but instead of opening it up (as it does currently) I would ideally like to automatically save it to a folder in my directory. I have had a look around and have found fwrite but I am not 100% sure if that is what i require. I should note that the code I am using is in a while loop so it can hit the $line part numerous times. The filename and fd part are outside of the loop.

(Outside of the loop)

```
$filename = "Product_category_list".date("j-m-Y_H.i"). ".csv";  

                $fd = fopen ($filename, "w");

                //The below is in a while loop

                                            $line = $separator . $sku_product . $separator . $delim; // Product SKU

                                            $line .= $separator . $sku . $separator . $delim; // SKU

                                            $line .= $separator . $category_lists . $separator . $delim; // Category Path

                                            $line .= $separator . $product_name . $separator . $delim; // Product Name

                                            $line .= $separator . $product_description . $separator . $delim; // Product Description

                                            $line .= $separator . $image_link. $separator . $delim; // Full Image

                                            $line .= $separator . $image_link_thumb. $separator . $delim; // Thumb Image

                                            $line .= $separator . $rrp_manual . $separator . $delim; // RRP

                                            $line .= $separator . $uk_wholesale . $separator . $delim; // Cost Price / Wholesale Price

                                            $line .= $separator . "GBP" . $separator . $delim; // Currency

                                            $line .= $separator . $tax_id . $separator . $delim; // Tax ID

                                            $line .= $separator . $discount . $separator . $delim; // Discount

                                            $line .= $separator . " " . $separator . $delim; // Discount End

                                            $line .= $separator . "1000" . $separator . $delim; // Product In Stock

                                            $line .= $separator . " " . $separator . $delim; // Product Special

                                            $line .= $separator . $delivery_front_text . $separator . $delim; // Product Availability

                                            $line .= $separator . "Y" . $separator . $delim; // Product Published


                                            $line .= $separator . $attribute_list . $separator . $delim; // Product Attribute

                                            $line .= $separator . $custom_attribute . $separator . $delim; // Custom Attribute - Could just be Please Enter your Personalisation Details Below (Only if Embroided Name or printed Initial)

                                            //$line .= $separator . " " . $separator . $delim; // Kitlocker Attribute - Size Guides

                                        //  $line .= $separator . " " . $separator . $delim; // Related Products

                                            //$line .= $separator . " " . $separator . $delim; // Alternative Products

                                        //  $line .= $separator . " " . $separator . $delim; // Colour Products

                                            $line .= $separator . $manu . $separator . $delim; // Manufacturer Name





                                            $contents .= $line . "\n";


    (outside of the loop)

    fputs($fd, $contents);

    fclose($fd);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either just run

```
while($condition){
    fwrite($fd, $data . ";\n");
}
```

in your loop instead of assigning it all to `$line` (in case of a big-big file, you might run out of memory) or if you insist on assigning all of your data to `$line` first, then remove the `fopen` and `fputs` lines and after your loop run `file_put_contents($filename, $contents);`

Answer (score 0):

The last time I did something like this, I used Headers.

```
Header("Content-type: application/csv");
Header("Content-disposition: attachment; 'Product_category_list'.date('j-m-Y_H.i').'.csv\'");
```

This will save the result of your PHP code to a CSV file. You can adjust your browser's setting to automatically save it to a specified location.